# Angular proxy not even working when it's working?

Tags: angular, proxy, asp.net-core-webapi

Writing 1st app with Angular front end and .Net Core WebAPI backing. VS2022 template builds and runs with a random weather forecast API. Front end relies on proxy.conf.js to find the .Net Core server, which works for template API, but not for my added APIs.

Even when duplicating the template API with just a change in name, the proxy only works for the unchanged name. I'm obviously missing some critical bit of proxy/API config, but even searching all occurrences of original name in project doesn't lead me to any other dependency on that name.

New APIs are published correctly, and, e.g., can be exercised in Swagger. Client just complains that it can't find it at the (wrong) URL.

Original service:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Renamed/Duplicate service:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class RandomWeatherController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<RandomWeatherController> _logger;

    public RandomWeatherController(ILogger<RandomWeatherController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetRandomWeather")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Accessing them on the client side with:

```
http.get<WeatherForecast[]>('/randomweather').subscribe(data => { this.forecasts = data; console.log("Results: "); console.log(data[0]); }, error => { console.log(error); });
http.get<WeatherForecast[]>('/weatherforecast').subscribe(data => { this.forecasts2 = data; console.log("Results: "); console.log(data[0]); }, error => { console.log(error); });
```

Using proxy.conf.js:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/api/*",
      "/random**",
      "/weather**"
    ],
    target: "https://localhost:7203",
    secure: false,
  }
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Gives me no redirection on 'random...', but works on 'weather...':

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'https://localhost:4200/randomweather', ok: false, …}
Results: 
{date: '2023-06-23', temperatureC: 40, temperatureF: 103, summary: 'Mild'}
```

Edit:
Changed the port in the proxy.conf.js target to something wrong (9999) & the behavior doesn't change, somehow the weatherforecast api is connecting and the randomweather api isn't. If I remove "/weather" from the context array it stops working until I add it back, which works even if the target is deliberately wrong.